# Why i can't write OBD 2 value of a car to firebase?

Tags: pi-3b+, python-3

Hello guys im having a problem sending a value to firebase

here's the code that i use

```
import obd

connection = obd.OBD("/dev/ttyAMA0")

while True:

    cmd1 = obd.commands.RPM 
    response1 = connection.query(cmd1)
    print(response1.value)

    cmd2 = obd.commands.SPEED 
    response2 = connection.query(cmd2)
    print(response2.value)

    cmd3 = obd.commands.SPEED 
    response3 = connection.query(cmd3)
    print(response3.value)
```

and it works
[image]

but when i connect it to the firebase

```
from firebase import firebase
import obd

FBConn = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://microbittempreader.firebaseio.com/', None)
connection = obd.OBD("/dev/ttyAMA0")

while True:

    cmd1 = obd.commands.RPM 
    response1 = connection.query(cmd1)

    cmd2 = obd.commands.SPEED 
    response2 = connection.query(cmd2)

    cmd3 = obd.commands.SPEED 
    response3 = connection.query(cmd3)

    data_to_upload = {
            'Engine RPM' : response1.value,
        'Vehicle Speed' : response2.value,
        'Engine_Load' : response3.value
        }

    result = FBConn.post('/MyTestData/',data_to_upload)

    print(result)
```

error: OBDresponse is not serialized

Comment: The datas dictionary must understand the type of `response1.value`, `response2.value`, `response3.value` i think, try : `str(response1.value)` and optionaly use urlencoding. I don't see any int() or float() value [here](https://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.